# Не коректная работа UPDATE в JPQL

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Есть запрос на обновление зарплаты работникам у которых есть неоплаченные заказы. Таких работников есть только 2, но в результате выполнения запроса обновляются зарплаты ВСЕХ работников. Если отдельно выполнить подзапрос `SELECT` он возвращает нужных работников, но в комбинации с `UPDATE` все работает плачевно...

Код запроса:

```
Query query1 = em.createQuery("UPDATE Employee e SET e.salary = e.salary * 0.8 WHERE e IN ( SELECT DISTINCT e1 FROM Employee e1 INNER JOIN Order o ON e1 = o.employee INNER JOIN OrderItem oi ON oi.order = o INNER JOIN Product p ON oi.product = p WHERE o.isPaid = 0 AND p.id = 13));

query1.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Попробуйте указывать `e` вместе с ид, вот так `...WHERE e.id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT e1.id FROM...`.

Comment: Так пробывал, результат аналогичный...

Comment: @БогданТкачук удалил свой ответ, так как к jpql он не имел никакого отношения.